# As a DM I gave our dwarf cleric a bear cub as a companion, what can I do?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, animal-companions, animals

So I'm with 2 PCs, playing D&D essentials kit. Most of the time we follow the plot, add some extra things there and here and of course doing some improve. I try to stick to some of the rules but not always, to make it more fun.

The PCs recently encountered a big brown bear and killed it. A bear cub appeared and they managed to persuade the cub to go with them and they have it now. I applied wolf stats to it (didn't give them the card yet, should I?). So now I'm thinking what this bear could do. I do not want to mobilize it as a fighting companion but make it more passive in battles and just help them with it's perception and some other goodies.

I was thinking:

1. Make the bear cub not grow with time, but rather give them an item to make the bear stronger in terms of constitution.
2. It mostly follows them and will not run away on it's own unless it's in life threatening danger.

Edit: Question: Do my two points make sense and what stats should I include any other mechanics that would work with this relationship between dwarf and bear? Should I allow mounting of the bear once it grows?

edit2: what stats and info can i reveal to my PC?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: At this state, your question is a bit open-ended and you don't specify exactly what the problem is. It most likely will be closed if you don't edit it.

Comment: To expand on Aventinus' comment, please bear in mind (see what I did there :P), as the DM you have the discretion to modify the rules as needed for the game. Are you seeking specific rules within the game to handle this situation? Or are you inquiring about the potential balance implications of permitting this companion?

Comment: Two things: You don't need to signal your edits (the revison history takes care of that)  and we ask that you don't because it makes things messy. Second, "Should" things generally depend heavily on preference. In general, we can't tell you how to play your game, but we might be able help with the decisionmaking, if we know enough about the situation (which I think is mostly fine) and your goals (which is maybe a spot vague?). You are going to get a better perception if you angle your question towards the latter.

Comment: There are existing rules for Animal Companions. Druids and Rangers should carry them. Arcana Casters have the somewhat similar familiar rules. 3.X also had the Leader feat, wich could be used to get followers. All those have in common that they try to balance the advantage, making sure you "paid for what you use". | But you also only have 2 Players. Depending on wich classes they are - and if those have any combat/wildness ability - it can be highly beneficial to have a fighting capable bear in the team. D&D is designed around a "well rounded party of 4". And it might just fill that need.

Comment: According to this answer, Leader was not translated to 5.0: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117230/bring-the-dd-3-5e-feat-leadership-to-5e-rules | A major issue with D&D and Animal Companions/Summons/Familiars/Leader Feat is the action economy. It gives the hero side way more actions then you balanced the encounters for. And it is not a constant amount of actions either. 4th Edition tried to solve that, by having all summons require being *commanded* to do something. Rule wise the player was sacrificing his action, to have the other thing act. The summon was more like a origin point.